# I want to set multiple sheets as the range for macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set multiple sheets(sheet1 , sheet2) at the start of the macro and at the moment it is not working.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("sheet1","sheet2")
    If Range("W6").Value = 0 Then
        Call HideFG
    Else
        Call HideF
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "want to set multiple sheets"? "It is not working" is never very helpful either - can you please elaborate?

Comment: In the second line, originally I only had sheet1 and it had no problems. And I added on sheet 2 so that it runs the IF ELSE on it too but the macro(IF ELSE) did not work. I am not sure why...

Comment: Your code doesn't reference a sheet though. Do you want to check the value of W6 in sheet1 and sheet2?

Comment: I want to reference both!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you appear to be trying to gather multiple sheets into one reference:

```
Set ws = Sheets("sheet1","sheet2")
```

You can *almost* do this with:

```
Sheets(Array("sheet1","sheet2"))
```

However, you have to work on one sheet at a time.. so  you need to use it like so:

```
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("sheet1", "sheet2"))

    If ws.Range("W6").Value = 0 Then
        Call HideFG
    Else
        Call HideF
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Great answer. Just for fun `If ws.[W6] = 0 Then` would also work :)

Answer (score 1):

Am I guessing right what You mean?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
            If .Range("W6").Value = 0 Then
                Call HideFG
            Else
                Call HideF
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```