# I want to reference several sheets for my macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to reference sheet 1, sheet 2 sheet 3 for my macro. At the moment, I referenced sheet 1 but I don't know how to reference multiple sheets. I hope that in all sheets, cell w6 is checked. Many thanks in advance! :)

Hide F macro is to hide a graph names "F" and show graph "FG" when cell w6 is not empty.
Hide FG macro is to hide a graph named "FG" and show graph "F" when cell w6 is empty.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    With ws
        If .Range("W6").Value = 0 Then
            HideFG
        Else
            HideF
        End If
    End With
Next

End Sub


Sub HideF()
'
' HideF Macro
'

'
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Visible = msoTrue
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("F")).Visible = msoFalse
    Application.CommandBars("Selection").Visible = False
End Sub


Sub HideFG()
'
' HideFG Macro
'

'
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Visible = msoTrue
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("FG")).Visible = msoFalse
    Application.CommandBars("Selection").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: This one is already answered : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57923615 - however you've added in the comment an additional problem (caused, we'd all guess - by `HideFG` and `HideF`). Again, guessing, you probably want to pass the sheet to those two procedures so they know which sheet to apply to but without sharing those two procedures with us we can't help further.

Comment: @CLR Thanks!, I add the F, FG macro. Can you please help me fine the source of problem :( ? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        With ws
            If .Range("W6").Value = 0 Then
                HideFG ws
            Else
                HideF ws
            End If
        End With
    Next

    End Sub


    Sub HideF(wsht As Worksheet)

    For i = 1 To wsht.Shapes.Count
        wsht.Shapes(i).Visible = msoTrue
    Next i
    wsht.Shapes.Range(Array("F")).Visible = msoFalse
    Application.CommandBars("Selection").Visible = False

End Sub


Sub HideFG(wsht As Worksheet)


    For i = 1 To wsht.Shapes.Count
        wsht.Shapes(i).Visible = msoTrue
    Next i
    wsht.Shapes.Range(Array("FG")).Visible = msoFalse
    Application.CommandBars("Selection").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Instead of just calling `HideFG`, the loop now calls it *with a reference* to the sheet that the loop is testing. So when `HideFG` is called, it 'knows' which sheet to make the changes to.

Notice that I've changed the lines where you attempt to hide the columns. Instead of setting `Visible` to False, you should set `Hidden` to True.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

You could also remove the need for two Hide procedures and replace them with one, where the column(s) to hide are included in the reference passed:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    With ws
        If .Range("W6").Value = 0 Then
            HideColumns ws.Columns("F:G")
        Else
            HideColumns ws.Columns("F")
        End If
    End With
Next

End Sub


Sub HideColumns(rng As Range)

    For i = 1 To rng.Parent.Shapes.Count
        rng.Parent.Shapes(i).Visible = msoTrue
    Next i
    rng.Hidden = msoTrue
    Application.CommandBars("Selection").Visible = False

End Sub
```

A final thought - presumably `[W6]` can change. Currently there is nothing in this code to unhide the columns if it does. You may need to consider this if changes can be made that result in the value of `[W6]` changing.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the HideF and Hide FG macro is not about hiding a column! It is related to hiding graphs named F and FG each. So if cell w6 is empty, graph FG should be hidden and only F should be shown and vice versa. In this case, how may I edit the code? Thank you

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I hadn't picked that up from your question. In that case, you'll need to find the reference for each graph and ignore my 'shorter' way.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help, I edited the HideF and HideFG macros in your original comment. I tried the code but is says "The index into the specified collection is out of bounds." in the wsht.Shapes(i).Visible = msoTrue line for the HideFG macro. Can you help me why such error is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        With ws
            If .Range("W6").Value = 0 Then
                HideFG
            Else
                HideF
            End If
        End With
    Next

    End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    With ws
        If .Range("W6").Value = 0 Then
            HideFG
        Else
            HideF
        End If
    End With
Next

End Sub


Sub HideF()
'
' HideF Macro
'

'
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Visible = msoTrue
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("F")).Visible = msoFalse
    Application.CommandBars("Selection").Visible = False
End Sub


Sub HideFG()
'
' HideFG Macro
'

'
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Visible = msoTrue
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("FG")).Visible = msoFalse
    Application.CommandBars("Selection").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but  it only works on one sheet, and the sheet that works gets randomly selected.

Comment: @MooChangPark what Teamothy wrote here is a loop which will iterate through every worksheet in your workbook. If `HideFG` or `HideF` end this loop there is nothing we can do because we don't know what these procedures do.

Comment: Thank you all! I added the Hide FG and Hide F macros. Can you help me out? Many thanks in advance