# "The item with the specified name wasn't found". error

Tags: excel, vba

I made the macro code so that it checks cell `"w6"` in all worksheets when the excel file opens. When `"w6"` is empty, it should hide graph `"FG"` and only show graph `"F"`. 
When `"w6"` is not empty, it should hide graph `"F"` and only show graph `"FG"`. I set the names of each graph as `"F"` and `"FG"`. But there is an error message in the 
`wsht.Shapes.Range(Array("FG")).Visible = msoFalse` line in the `HideFG` macro that "the item with the specified name wasn't found." I am sure that the graph name is `"FG"`, but why is this happening? Is there an excel genius who can solve this?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        With ws
            If .Range("W6").Value = 0 Then
                HideFG ws
            Else
                HideF ws
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub

Sub HideF(wsht As Worksheet)

'
' HideF Macro
'

'
    For i = 1 To wsht.Shapes.Count
    wsht.Shapes(i).Visible = msoTrue
    Next i

    wsht.Shapes.Range(Array("F")).Visible = msoFalse
    Application.CommandBars("Selection").Visible = False

End Sub

Sub HideFG(wsht As Worksheet)

'
' HideFG Macro
'

'
    For i = 1 To wsht.Shapes.Count
    wsht.Shapes(i).Visible = msoTrue
    Next i

    wsht.Shapes.Range(Array("FG")).Visible = msoFalse
    Application.CommandBars("Selection").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe it's because you're not specifying which shape to choose. In the loops you specify like `Shapes(i)`, but in the next part it doesn't know which shape to hide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling another macro, you could just simply try the following:

If what you refer to are actually `Shapes`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Shapes.Range(Array("F", "FG")).Visible = False
    If ws.[W6] = 0 Then
        ws.Shapes("F").Visible = True
    Else
        ws.Shapes("FG").Visible = True
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Or when they actually are `ChartObjects` then:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.[W6] = 0 Then
        ws.ChartObjects("F").Visible = True
        ws.ChartObjects("FG").Visible = False
    Else
        ws.ChartObjects("F").Visible = False
        ws.ChartObjects("FG").Visible = True
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

---

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57923615/i-want-to-set-multiple-sheets-as-the-range-for-macro) question of yours, I feel you might not want to loop all the sheets.

In that case, change:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
```

Into:

```
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3"))
```

Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: Thank you for the help :) I copy and pasted the code and it says "the item with the specified item wasn't found" for the "ws.Shapes.Range(Array("F", "FG")).Visible = False" line :(

Comment: I am sure that i assigned the graph name to both F and FG graph. I don't know why such message appears...

Comment: Thanks for the help, now it shows the  "the item with the specified item wasn't found" message with "ws.ChartObjects("FG").Visible = False"   The chart is a normal bar chart :)

Comment: it is a big mystery... The chart name is correct... but why does it say it cannot find it... I am so lost..

Comment: @MooChangPark, remember that, as per your last question, you might not want to loop through all the sheets. When a chart doesn't exists, it will throw you that error!

Comment: Oh,,,, that is why! Yes because the F and FG charts only exist in sheet 1, sheet 2 and sheet 3 among 6different sheets... In this case, how may change the vba? I am very grateful for your help

Comment: Yes, It is now solved :) You are the nicest person, thank you so much for the patience and help. I wish you the best of luck ! Have a great day, Thanks again you are a genius